# Using libsvm for text classification c#

Tags: c#, libsvm

I am using libsvm to predict sentiment. I wanted to know what format the input has to be in
assuming I am using word count.

```
     [label] [index]:[value] [index]:[value]
```

That is required format from libsvm. So does that mean I just have two labels ( one for positive and one for negative), the index would be each word under that label and the value would be the frequency of each word ?

Does this also mean I need to store the mapping of word to index to use in my test set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIBSVM uses the so called "sparse" format where zero values do not need to be stored. Hence a data with attributes
5 0 2 0
is represented as
1:5 3:2
Therefore, you only need to specifiy the **index** and the **value** of *nonzero* attributes.

**Labels** stand in the first column. For binary cases you may use +1 for positive and -1 for negative samples. By the way, you are not limited to only 2 labels. You can use other numbers (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,...)

Comment: Okay so 5 would represent the count of the word in that particular sentence ( assuming we do it sentence wise) and 1 would represent the index of the word in a dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the sample file given in libsvm. It is called heart_scale. Follow that...It is a good example...