# training libsvm for text classification(sentiment)

Tags: svm, libsvm, sentiment-analysis

From following links I came with some idea. I want to ask whether I am doing it right or I am in the wrong way. If I am in the wrong way, please guide me.

Links
[Using libsvm for text classification c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021658/using-libsvm-for-text-classification-c-sharp)
[How to use libsvm for text classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172159/how-to-use-libsvm-for-text-classification)

My way

First calculate the word count in each training set
Create a maping list for each word

eg

```
sample word count form training set
|-----|-----------|
|     |   counts  |
|-----|-----|-----|
|text | +ve | -ve |
|-----|-----|-----|
|this | 3   | 3   |
|forum| 1   | 0   |
|is   | 10  | 12  |
|good | 10  | 5   |
|-----|-----|-----|
```

positive training data

```
this forum is good
```

so will the training set be

```
+1 1:3 2:1 3:10 4:10
```

this all is just what I received from above links.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it right.

I don't know why your laben is called "+1" - should be a simple integer (refering to the document "+ve"), but all in all it's the way to go.

For document classification you may want to take a look at liblinear which is specially designed for handling a lot of features.

Comment: also other thing, since my sample word count index and my training word index matches, will the index be from training word "this forum is good" or the index from sample word count?

also, what if one word is repeating? like "this forum is very very good" if "very" word has count 3 what will new training set be?

Comment: First, that's not a question for Stackoverflow, but: Don't know if I got you right, but basically you need sets of features (= documents with attributes) which you put into the svm. Each set belongs to the first or the second document class (1 or 2). The support vector machine will then split them into 2 sets by calculating a margin between them. When you now feed the svm with an unclassified/unknown document, it will check to which classified set it belongs and return the result (you really should read wikipedia).

Comment: For getting the features/attributes you could create a dictionary which maps words to ids. Like in your example the word "this" got the id 1, "forum"-2 and so on. Of course you use the same word<->id associations for ALL your documents, so you'll need a centralized dictionary.

Comment: In your example you use "1 1:3 2:1 3:10 4:10" for your training set. This means you describe the "+ve" document - the word with id 1 appears 3 times in the document, the word with id 2 one time. and so on... In your last example ("this forum is very very good") the featureset would be: "this forum is very very good" "1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:2" where 5 is a new id for the word "very" (which is safed in the dictionary for later use).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use libshorttext from here:
[libshortText](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/)

in python